# Why the duplicated venv name in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I am trying to setup a virtualenv in VSCode. It seems fine, however, it somehow requires 'duplicating' the venv command in order for the environment to work properly. For example:

[image]

Notice how it has:

```
(venv) (venv)
```

When it is in the virtualenv

And it has:

```
(venv)
```

When it is not in it. What's going on here? Another wonky thing is it says that the `venv` is activated in the lower-right, but when actually going into the python shell we can see that it's not -- it's 2.7:

[image]

Compare with doing the same thing in my normal shell:

[image]

Finally, here is a video reproducing when this works and when it does not: https://gyazo.com/677f83b1aaeb249f7f817670b7820e64.

Comment: The activate scripts apparently got run twice and didn't detect the second run as being unneeded, thus adding the name twice. The deactivate script still only returns to the previous prompt (inlcuding the name), so that explains what you're seeing. Why it happens is hard to say without more information. Also, please [don't use images when sharing code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @Grismar the `$ (venv)` is not an actual virtualenv though, it's just giving that name somehow but not actually initializing the environment. You can see that with the python 2.7 vs. python3.9

Comment: @Grismar understood, but this seems to be more an interface error and not really any code involved.

Comment: I know - but the `activate` script is what modifies the prompt, simply by adding the name to the start. Normally it wouldn't do that twice, but clearly something happens to allow it to run twice without detecting it was already run (or perhaps running).

Comment: @Grismar it seems to happen when I run `$ code .` from within a virtualenv to open up VS Code. But if I open vscode not coming from a virtualenv, it seems to act ok.

Comment: You can activate the virtual environment in the vscode terminal. Using commands to open vscode and activate a virtual environment in an additional command line window can easily cause confusion in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same thing in my setup (WSL2, running Ubuntu 22.04 with a tensorflow virtual environment; Visual Studio running on Win11 and remotely accessing the python environment on WSL2). I can avoid the double "(tf) (tf)" when I do *not* activate the "tf" virtual environment from by `.bashrc` script. It seems that Visual Studio Code automatically opens another virtual environment on top of the already running one. If your setup is similar to mine, just comment out the `source ~/tf/bin/activate` statement in your `.bashrc` script, if you have it.